# How do I make command blocks that imitate a note block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know the command that is required and the possible combinations for the variable that changes the pitch.

Comment: What do you mean with individual Notes?

Comment: @ardaozkal by individual notes I mean like if you were ever in Band Choir or Orchestra things like F# and G

Comment: Are you looking for how to change the pitch of a sound? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible using this command:

```
/playsound (sound) @a X Y Z (Volume) (pitch)
```

Note: Pitch has to be 0-2. 0 is the lowest pitch, and 2 is the highest. You can use decimals such as *0.2* or *1.8*.

Here is a list of all the sounds in minecraft:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json

You can play custom sounds that are in resource packs in the same manner.

## Sounds of Noteblocks:

`note.snare`
A Note Block that is on top of a "sand" block is clicked or powered by redstone.

`note.pling`
None

`note.hat`
A Note Block that is on top of a "glass" block is clicked or powered by redstone.

`note.harp`
A Note Block that is on top of an "other" block is clicked or powered by redstone.

`note.bd`
A Note Block that is on top of a "stone" block is clicked or powered by redstone.

`note.bassattack`
A Note Block that is on top of a "wood" block is clicked or powered by redstone.

`note.bass`
None

Comment: = Incomplete Answer | How about pitch?

Comment: Pitch can go from 0 to 2. and you can also use decimals; for example: 1.2

Comment: You should [edit] it in.

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can the command to make a music note use /playsound (sound file name).ogg